# Perl script to merge multiple files line by line

Tags: perl, file-io

Can anyone please help me with writing a Perl script which can take as input 5 text files and create a new text file with merging each row of all 5 files. 
Should this be done by opening 5 read streams at a time or like java some random file reader is available in Perl ?

Thank You!

Comment: Yes, you can open 5 files at once (and far more than that) in Perl.  Have you tried at all to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Do you mean line1 of file1, line1 of file2,..., line2 of file1, line2 of file2... ?

Comment: yes Guru, exactly I mean that.  Yes dan1111, I tried but I doing something wrong. Will copy paste the code after clearing it up a bit. Thanks for responding. And my apologies for not posting my code with question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program expects a list of files on the command line (or, on Unix systems, a wildcard file spec). It creates an array of filehandles `@fh` for these files and then reads from each of them in turn, printing the merged data to `STDOUT`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fh;
for (@ARGV) {
  open my $fh, '<', $_ or die "Unable to open '$_' for reading: $!";
  push @fh, $fh;
}

while (grep { not eof } @fh) {
  for my $fh (@fh) {
    if (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
      chomp $line;
      print "$line\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If one of the files does not end with a newline, two lines will get merged into one at that point.

Comment: +1: `grep { not eof } @fh` is a nice improvement compared to what I had come up with.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Perl script that will work on an arbitrary number of files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = ('a.txt','b.txt');
my @fh;

#create an array of open filehandles.
@fh = map { open my $f, $_ or die "Cant open $_:$!"; $f } @files;

open my $out_file, ">merged.txt" or die "can't open out_file: $!";

my $output;
do
{
    $output = '';

    foreach (@fh)
    {
        my $line = <$_>;
        if (defined $line)
        {
            #Special case: might not be a newline at the end of the file
            #add a newline if none is found.
            $line .= "\n" if ($line !~ /\n$/);
            $output .= $line;
        }
    }

    print {$out_file} $output;
}
while ($output ne '');
```

a.txt:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

b.txt:

```
bar1
bar2
bar3
```

merged.txt:

```
foo1
bar1
foo2
bar2
foo3
bar3
foo4
foo5
```

Comment: The `$_= $f` in your `map` call will replace all the file names in `@files` with their file handles so it will and up with the same data as in `@fh`. I assume you don't want that, so you should use just `$f` instead of assigning to `$_`

Answer (score 5):

If a non-perl solution is ok with you, you can try this:

```
paste -d"\n\n\n\n\n" f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
```

where f1,f2..are your text files.

Comment: What is this ? I did not get it

Comment: @Andy897: paste is a POSIX standard utility program that does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: @Guru: `paste -d "\n" f1 f2 f3 f4 f5` is sufficient